# Unable to Connect to PostgreSQL Server hosted on a Virtual Machine from my local machine

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14, postgresql-15

I am trying to connect to a Remote PostgreSQL Server(WINDOWS 8 Server) from my local machine (WINDOWS 10 Machine) and i am getting connection timeout error.

I have tried following things before posting this question.

1. Checked and made sure that `listen_addresses` in postgresql.conf should be set to `'*'` on the server end.
2. 2nd thing, allowed any ip address to communicate with host(i know its a bad practice but for development purpose) I have replaced the local host ipaddress with `0.0.0.0/0`  in `pg_hba.conf` file.

Something like below -

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            scram-sha-256
```

3. Whitelisting the PostgreSQL Port number by adding the Port Number - `5433` in the inbound rules section in Windows Firewall Advanced Settings on PostgreSQL Server machine (WIN 8 Server).
4. After performing above steps, I have restarted the PostgreSQL.

My local environment

```
WINDOWS 10 Machine
PostgreSQL 14 
PGAdmin4
Port Number - Default 5432
```

My Server Environment

```
WINDOWS 8 Machine
PostgreSQL 15
PgAdmin 4
Port Number - Default 5433
```

I have tried PGAdmin4/PSQL to connect to this remote server but everytime its failing with time out error.

Please let me know what else needs to be done here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a networking problem, such as with a firewall or NAT. Bad settings for postgresql.conf or pg_hba.conf will not generate connection timeout errors, they will fail in different ways.

Comment: Just one more thing, on that Windows Server , a SQL server instance is also running which i can connect with ippadress , username and password from my local machine using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes , yes you are right, its related to some network issue, both the machines (my local and Server machine)are on different networks. I tried connecting the PostgreSQL hosted on the Server machine with some other machine on the same network and I was able to do it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this as this could be someone else's problem as well.

The problem was not related to `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`. I checked if the port is open for communication on the WINDOWS server using command `netstat -an |find /i "5433"` and found that the Port was showing  as `listening` which means its open for communication.
The reason was **some network issue**, the Network on which the remote machine lies is different from the one which my local machine is using and seems like there's a firewall in between which is blocking the Port Number from communication.

Thanks